# Where to write server-specific parameters?

Tags: symfony

For some custom Bundles of my application, I need to define some parameters (mainly folder/file path). Some of them are different depending on if I'm on my local test server or my remote prod server and some are common to both.

How should I manage these parameters?

I had the idea to create such kind of file:

- MyFirstBundle/Resources/config/parameters_local.yml
- MyFirstBundle/Resources/config/parameters_distant.yml
- MySecondBundle/Resources/config/parameters_local.yml
- MySecondBundle/Resources/config/parameters_distant.yml

And then import them respectively in app/config/parameters_local.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: @MyFirstBundle/Resources/config/parameters_local.yml }
    - { resource: @MySecondBundle/Resources/config/parameters_local.yml }
```

and app/config/parameters_distant.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: @MyFirstBundle/Resources/config/parameters_distant.yml }
    - { resource: @MySecondBundle/Resources/config/parameters_distant.yml }
```

But this is a bit heavy, especially when I have only one or two parameters in a Bundle or when I have parameters which are common to local and distant server.

What is the good way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#validation-and-merging-with-a-configuration-class), you can define a default configuration in your bundle for your prod environment :

```
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme_hello');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('my_param_1')->defaultValue('foo')->end()
            ->scalarNode('my_param_2')->defaultValue('bar')->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And in your app/config/config_dev.yml you just override parameters that are different from prod ones :

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
acme_hello:
    my_param_2: baz
```

Et hop !